# Transparent direct3d rendering context

Tags: c#, xna, directx, rendering

I want to make a transparent rendering context using XNA, so when the 3d model is rendered the desktop  and any other background programs should be visible. If i could not use unmanaged code would be great.[image]

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: not sure if this is possible, you can try capturing screen background and show as background in form. you will need position and size of form to show only that part of image what is behind form.

Comment: @lauCosma What is the question exactly? On your screenshot I see C# code in VS through window with transparent background and models drawn. Isn't it exactly what you need?

Comment: Nope... i did that to explain the question... the image is just a png with an empty form. I need a **transparent rendering context**. I have found a post (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28526/Introduction-to-D3DImage) but is using direct3d and i was wondering if you can do this in XNA(because it uses direct3d).

Comment: @lauCosma I think that might be possible. I have realized a similar approach with SlimDX. What you would basically do is creating an XNA device and a surface as the render target and then set this render target as the back buffer of the WPF D3DImage. However, you should keep in mind that you can't use XNA's game class because it creates a window and handles the rendering on its own. Just try it.

Comment: i have managed to use the XNA framework in an window application (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21330/Easy-Rendering-with-XNA-Inside-a-Windows-Form) and the game content but i got stuck with the transparent window part. Thank you @NicoSchertler! I will give it a try and feedback.